# Jest Tests not running with jest-mongodb preset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I have a set up a the [jest starter](https://github.com/hamzahamidi/jest-starter) to get integration tests running against an in memory mongodb with [jest-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelf/jest-mongodb)

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb",
```

However, running npx jest all I get is

```
> jest-starter@1.0.0 test my/path/jest-starter
> jest

Determining test suites to run...(node:10769) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

If I run the tests without jest-mongodb it runs fine. In our CI the tests also will execute fine.

```
> jest-starter@1.0.0 test /my/path/jest-starter
> jest

 PASS  ./index.spec.js
  ✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (3ms)
  ✓ adds 5 + 8 to equal 13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.503s
Ran all test suites.
```

I have Windows 10 with ubuntu subsystem.

node version 13.9.0

npm version 6.13.7

package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },      
    "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^1.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  }
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the solution. I was on the right track, the error was caused by the ubuntu subsystem. Found the solution at [the github page for jest-mongodb](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb/issues/179)

Ubuntu is missing a dependency required by jest-mongodb:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```

solved it.